# Error: Maximum width and height dimension for upload image is 5000

Tags: image, magento, image-uploading

I have an automatically upload for product-images.
The images are uploaded but i don't see them.
I get the error: Maximum width and height dimension for upload image is 5000
The image is correct uploaded in the media/catalog/product folder.

It is Magento 1.9.3.2

How can i solve this error?

Answer (score 1):

It's happening because of the patch SUPEE-8788.

So you can fix that on the admin panel on this route:

**System > Configuration > Catalog > Product Image**

[image: Magento image size limit to upload]

Comment: Still there even after changing the size to 50.000 BTW what does this limit is not clear at all to me.